# 1 SSL-Certificate for 2 Apps?

Tags: security, ssl, canvas, https, facebook-canvas

We provide several gaming apps. We now have to integrate SSL certificates to handle the new HTTPS guidelines on facebook. My question is:

Do we have to use different URLs for our facebook games like

1. facebook.game1.com & facebook.game2.com => Here we need to buy and implement several SSL-certificates, right?
2. or can we stick to a single domain like facebook.company.com and use subdomains for our games? => Is it possible to implement just one SSL certificate?

Where can I find further information?

THX a lot!!!!

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how many ip addresses you have.

Q1> if you have 1 ip address, you should get the SAN certificate that handles multiple domains - http://www.ssl.com/subject_alternative_name gives a good explanation on what a SAN is useful for. If you have 1 ip per domain, then you can get by with a cheap standard SSL certificate for each ip address.

Q2> if you have 1 ip address, this would be where a [wildcard](http://www.ssl.com/certificates/wildcard) comes in handy. If you have 1 ip per domain, then you can get by with a cheap standard SSL certificate for each ip address as mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

Well firstly you can create more than one application per domain... I have two applications both sitting in the same domain only in different folders. 
EG :

```
App1
https://my.domain.info/app1/

App2
https://my.domain.info/app2/
```

If you want different sub domains, eg app1.domain.info and app2.domain.info, you will have to purchase (an expensive) wildcard ssl certificate...

Hope this sheds some light on your question!

Answer (score 0):

In regards to Q1, you can have both on one SSL cert. This type of certs is call Unified Communication Cert.

In regards to Q2, yes you can implement one SSL cert in this case it will be a wildcard certificate.

UNC certs are cheaper than wildcard certs.

DigiCert do have good breakdown in regards to SSL certificates types http://www.digicert.com/welcome/product-overview.htm